# Is it possible to to make many $scope variables in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to receive from server some JSON data and print it like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="pastController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{ x.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="y in names1">
      <td>{{ y.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="z in names2">
    <td>{{ z.shops }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and my angular script:

```
app.controller('pastController', function($scope, $http){
  var req = {
    method: 'post', 
    url: 'showData'
  };

  $http(req).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data.pastData);
    $scope.names = response.data.pastData;
    $scope.names2 = response.data.presentData;
    $scope.names1 = response.data.futureData;
  });
});
```

and here is like my json response looks like:

```
     {
       "pastData" : 
         [
           {"id":1, "shopPlace":"warsaw", "shopDate":"2016-08-10", "shops":"milk"},
           {"id":2, "shopPlace":"warsaw", "shopDate":"2016-09-10", "shops":"table"}
         ],
      "futureData" : 
        [
          {"id":3, "shopPlace":"krakow", "shopDate":"2016-12-10", "shops":"bread"}, 
          {"id":4, "shopPlace":"kielce", "shopDate":"2016-11-20", "shops":"water"}
        ],
      "presentData" : 
        [
          {"id":5, "shopPlace":"wroclaw", "shopDate":"2016-11-07", "shops":"sugar"}
        ] 
      }
```

Everything works fine for names and only for names for names1 it shows : {{ y.shops }} and for names2: {{ z.shops }}

Comment: Looks like your child bindings are off. Should be y.shops and z.shops in your second/third ng-repeats.

Comment: You should include an example of the response JSON in your question.

Comment: I ve changed my html to x, y, z but it still doesnt work

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the reason for the request of JSON data.  The question revolves *entirely* around why `presentData` and `futureData` aren't being bound, so seeing what is in that data is necessary to fully troubleshoot the problem.  providing the data that works, and then abbreviating the data that doesn't work doesn't provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: i edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html markup is incorrect. Your last table is outside the scope of your controller. This is very easy to see when the markup is properly formatted.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="pastController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{ x.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="y in names1">
      <td>{{ y.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="z in names2">
    <td>{{ z.shops }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

One problem that I see immediately is that the markup for your 3rd table is outside of the div where the angular application and controller have scope, it should be inside. However, if your second table is not being displayed either, then there must be another issue. Here is a working plunker demonstrating everything working. Note that the data is hardcoded instead of being fetched from an API:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZbJeatH1SkkVDxqNkQ0b?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="pastController">
   <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{ x.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="y in names1">
      <td>{{ y.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="z in names2">
      <td>{{ z.shops }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('pastController', function($scope, $http) {
    var data =  {
        "pastData" : [{"id":1, "shopPlace":"warsaw", "shopDate":"2016-08-10", "shops":"milk"}, {"id":2, "shopPlace":"warsaw", "shopDate":"2016-09-10", "shops":"table"}],
        "futureData" : [{"id":3, "shopPlace":"krakow", "shopDate":"2016-12-10", "shops":"bread"}, {"id":4, "shopPlace":"kielce", "shopDate":"2016-11-20", "shops":"water"}],
        "presentData" : [{"id":5, "shopPlace":"wroclaw", "shopDate":"2016-11-07", "shops":"sugar"}]
    };

    $scope.names = data.pastData;
    $scope.names2 = data.presentData;
    $scope.names1 = data.futureData;
});
```